# How to use files already minified in React js (create-reat-app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Please, I would like to know if there is a way to add files already minified in a **react project** created with **react-create-app**. Basically, I can not add it in the HTML file because it runs before the file bundle.js (and the opposite is what I look for). I obviously can not add it in the js and it is a file that can not be recovered via npm. How to add this kind of vendor files as we can not overload the React webpack.

After looking in the documentation and reading several articles, I find hardly anything about it

Comment: What is the minified vendor file? What is the documentation you are referring to? What is `it`?

Comment: `require` it and compile it into your bundle.js?